# Using Hapi.js run a third party command line tool

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

In my application I need to use a command line tool but I have not seen any way to do it without using a npm module. I am using core node except for the command line tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use node's [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module. Here is an example where the [`touch`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch) command is called in the handler:

```
var ChildProcess = require('child_process');
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        ChildProcess.exec('touch example.txt', function (err) {

            console.log('FILE CREATED');
        });

        process.on('exit', function (code) {

            console.log('PROCESS FINISHED');
            reply();
        });
    }
});

server.inject('/', function (res) { });
```

Comment: sweet this is exactly what I am looking for.
So I could do something like 
ChildProcess.exec('imageMagick -convert ' + filename + '.pdf ' + filename + '.png'); to convert an uploaded pdf file to png.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just make sure `filename` is properly escaped. If you just concatenate the strings, users can use the filename to run malicious code on the server.

Comment: What is being injected to server?

Comment: It's just to test the code. You won't need to use it in your production code.

Comment: See documentation: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#serverinjectoptions-callback